# How to paste files using Applescript (or bash)?

Tags: finder, applescript, bash, copy-paste

I want to paste a file copied by Finder in the terminal. Sth like pbpaste but for binaries. (pbpaste itself just returns the basename of the copied file.)

Comment: What should happen afterwards, where do you want to paste the file content *to*?

Comment: May be related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/362245/copy-file-from-terminal-and-paste-in-mail

Comment: @nohillside I want `pastefile DIR` to paste the file into DIR.

Comment: Something like `cp $(pbpaste) DIR` then?

Comment: @nohillside pbpaste just pastes the basename, not the complete path.

Comment: Right, just noticed that. Hmm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way I can think of doing this is to use a little bit of AppleScriptObjC.  It provides access to the various data type representations on the clipboard, and in multiple.

After retrieving the full file paths, these can then be passed to the `cp` command.

Wrapping this in a bash function declaration:

```
pastefiles() {
    IFS=$'\n'
    fs=($( osascript -e "use framework \"Foundation\"
        property this : a reference to the current application
        property NSPasteboard : a reference to NSPasteboard of this
        property NSURL : a reference to NSURL of this
        property pb : a reference to NSPasteboard's generalPasteboard

        property text item delimiters : linefeed

        pb's readObjectsForClasses:[NSURL] options:[]
        (result's valueForKey:\"path\") as list as text" ))

    cp -r "${fs[@]}" "$1"
}
```

**Usage:** `pastefiles`*`~/Example/Destination/Path`*

You can add this to your `.bashrc` file to have the function available to each new shell session.

Comment: In macOS 10.15 Catalina, Apple has replace the previous default shell, `bash`, with `zsh`.Do you know if this will this work **as is** if placed in the e.g. users `.zprofile` or `.zshrc` file?

Comment: @user3439894 I don't know, I'm afraid.  Not used _`zsh`_ before. I use _`FiSh`_ as my default shell.