# Triggering a paste from the command line

Tags: macos, terminal, automation, window-manager, copy-paste

Is there any way to trigger a paste in the windows manager, for example, if I got a text box focused in an application, say, Safari, and I run the command from the command line, it would trigger a paste in the active text box. In short, it would trigger command-v

What I'm hoping to achieve is being able to create scripts, that i can then call from skhd. So, scripts that'd do something ala

```
pbcopy < stuff.txt
magic-paste-into-focused-component
```

ish..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you will have to `pbpaste` to a temporary file, validate it’s in the clipboard and then [trigger the keys for the application of your choosing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/362246/5472). There will be [many specific details](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/15484/5472) for each part of the chain you will have to get right.

The copy and dumping a file into the clipboard is covered on another question here as is the management of the paste operation.

Comment: Automation is so awesome - enjoy